# ROS 1: How to programatically write static transforms to a bag file so that rviz "sees" it

Tags: ros, ros-noetic

I'm having an issue with an application that programmatically creates ROS bag files using the rosbag code API (http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API). Then I want to be able to playback and visualize the created ROS bags using a custom rviz configuration.

The only piece that isn't working is the static transforms. For some reason, rviz doesn't seem to be able to "see" the transforms written to the /tf_static topic when I play back the generated bag file. The weird thing is that other applications do: I can run things like rqt_tf_tree and tf_echo and those are able to read the static transforms fine, so I feel like there must be some nuance that I'm missing. Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Start rviz first before running the "rosbag play" command, which would theoretically mean there shouldn't be any issues with latched topics.
2. Use simulated time when playing back the log.
3. Just write everything to the "/tf" topic instead, but then we get extrapolation issues when doing lookups.
4. Edit the timestamps on the static transforms so that they come after the log start time

**EDIT #2-- What exactly am I trying to do?**

I think this is a weirdly specific/unusual case, which might be why I haven't been able to find a solution through googling. I have a node that is subscribing to both /tf and /tf_static, and when it receives a message it just stores that message in a list, alongside the ros::time::now() that the message was received. It stores a few other messages in the same way, but the important thing is that it's not just storing messages that were published, some of it is data that's internal to the node. I bring this up only to explain why I'm doing it this way instead of just using "rosbag record."

On certain conditions, this node is supposed to dump the last 20 seconds worth of data to a bag file, and I use the rosbag code API. So, create a rosbag::bag object and then make a bunch of write() calls. I have to have a special condition for the static transforms here, because those might not be in the last 20 seconds worth of data but they still need to be in the bag file that gets written out.

**EDIT #1-- Adding clarification as to exactly what the issue is**

So here's what rqt_tf_tree looks like. There are a LOT of frames, but I think it's enough to just zoom in and look at the three frames highlighted below:
[image]

So the link between "grizzlyC/odom" and "grizzlyC/base_footprint" is dynamic and published on "/tf", and the link between "grizzlyC/base_footprint" and "grizzlyC/base_link" is static and published on "/tf_static". So far this is exactly what I expect to see.

But when I playback the log when running rviz, I get errors like this:
[image]

The error at the bottom is saying it can't find a connection between "odom" and "base_link." For the axes display, if I change the reference frame to "base_footprint" then it does find the connection and displays fine.

If I do a "rostopic echo /tf_static", I see this:

```
transforms: 
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 1700496971
        nsecs: 513109186
      frame_id: "grizzlyC/base_footprint"
      child_frame_id: "grizzlyC/base_link"
  ...
  (continues)
```

Comment: Can you share a short bag of /tf_static?  Also add a portion of `rostopic echo /tf_static` to your question, and a screenshot of rqt_tf_tree would help

Comment: What do you mean when you say "rviz doesn't seem to be able to 'see' the transforms?" If you `rostopic echo` the topic that isn't getting visualized correctly, what frame_id is it using and what frame_id is tf_static publishing? If you can see the frames in rqt_tf_tree then rviz should have them just fine, but if you're not publishing content to those frames then that would be a good reason why rviz isn't visualizing them as expected.

Comment: Okay, will do-- I'm editing the question now.

Comment: `roswtf` looks at your tf tree (among other things) and can sometimes tell you something helpful, for example it'll warn about multiple parents to the same tf child.  [tf_tree.py](https://github.com/lucasw/tf_demo/blob/old_tf_to_new_tf/scripts/tf_tree.py) should be similar to rqt_tf_tree but shows the output in text, maybe can tell you something useful, also there's `rosrun tf2_tools echo.py odom base_link` which is the tf2 version of the older tf echo- all these are sort of redundant but also have different implementations that may give clues to what's going on that a different tool missed.

Comment: For `3` how are you writing everything to `/tf`?  If you use the older `tf static_transform_publisher` (which publishes to /tf at a specified rate as opposed to `tf2_ros static_transform_publisher` which publishes once latched to /tf_static) it will future-date the transforms which should prevent extrapolation lookup errors, if you have a custom node publishing static transforms to tf you could do the same thing: publish at 10Hz but add 0.1 seconds to every timestamp (or 1Hz and add 1s).